# Find this ODE solution $(y-x)\sqrt{x^2+1}\dfrac{dy}{dx}=(1+y^2)^{\frac{3}{2}}$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Find all solutions $y$ to the ODE

$$(y-x)\sqrt{x^2+1}\dfrac{dy}{dx}=(1+y^2)^{\frac{3}{2}}$$

My try:
$$(y-x)\dfrac{d(\sqrt{1+y^2})}{y}=\dfrac{(1+y^2)dx}{\sqrt{x^2+1}}$$
then
$$\dfrac{(y-x)\cdot d(\sqrt{1+y^2})}{y(1+y^2)}=\dfrac{d(\sqrt{1+x^2})}{x}$$

then I can't.Thank you for you help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\newcommand{\+}{^{\dagger}}
 \newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle #1 \right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace #1 \right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack #1 \right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\,\left\lceil #1 \right\rceil\,}
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}
 \newcommand{\down}{\downarrow}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\equalby}[1]{{#1 \atop {= \atop \vphantom{\huge A}}}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\isdiv}{\,\left.\right\vert\,}
 \newcommand{\ket}[1]{\left\vert #1\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\ol}[1]{\overline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left( #1 \right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,#2\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}$
$\ds{\pars{y - x}\root{x^{2} + 1}\,\totald{y}{x} = \pars{1 + y^{2}}^{3/2}}$

> With $\ds{x \equiv \tan\pars{\alpha}}$ and $\ds{y \equiv \tan\pars{\beta}}$ we get:
>   $$\!\!\!\!\!
> \bracks{\tan\pars{\beta} - \tan\pars{\alpha}}\sec\pars{\alpha}\,
> {\sec^{2}\pars{\beta} \over \sec^{2}\pars{\alpha}}\,\totald{\beta}{\alpha}
> =\sec^{3}\pars{\beta}\ \imp\
> \bracks{\tan\pars{\beta} - \tan\pars{\alpha}}\cos\pars{\alpha}\cos\pars{\beta}\,
> \totald{\beta}{\alpha} = 1
> $$

$$
\bracks{\sin\pars{\beta}\cos\pars{\alpha} - \sin\pars{\alpha}\cos\pars{\beta}}\,
\totald{\beta}{\alpha}= 1\quad\imp\quad
\totald{\beta}{\alpha} = {1 \over \sin\pars{\beta - \alpha}}
$$

> With $u = \beta - \alpha$
>   $$
> \totald{u}{\alpha} + 1 = {1 \over \sin\pars{u}}\quad\imp\quad
> \bracks{-1 + {1 \over 1 - \sin\pars{u}}}\,\totald{u}{\alpha} = 1
> $$

$$
-u + \int{\dd u \over 1 - \sin\pars{u}} = \alpha + C\,,\qquad C\ \mbox{is a constant}
$$

> Also, with $t = \tan\pars{u/2}$:
>   \begin{align}
> \int{\dd u \over 1 - \sin\pars{u}}&=
> \int{1 \over 1 - 2t/\pars{1 + t^{2}}}\,{2\,\dd t \over t^{2} + 1}
> =2\int{\dd t \over \pars{t - 1}^{2}} = -\,{2 \over t - 1}
> ={2 \over 1 - \tan\pars{u/2}}
> \\[3mm]&=2\,{\cos\pars{u/2} \over \cos\pars{u/2} - \sin\pars{u/2}}
> ={2\cos^{2}\pars{u/2} + 2\cos\pars{u/2}\sin\pars{u/2} \over \cos\pars{u}}
> \\[3mm]&={1 + \cos\pars{u} + \sin\pars{u} \over \cos\pars{u}}
> =\sec\pars{u} + 1 + \tan\pars{u}
> \end{align}

Then,
$$
-\beta + \sec\pars{\beta - \alpha} + \tan\pars{\beta - \alpha} = \mbox{constant}
$$
which is an implicit relation between $\alpha = \arctan\pars{x}$ and
$\beta = \arctan\pars{y}$:
$$
-\arctan\pars{y} + {\sqrt{\pars{y - x}^{2} + \pars{1 + yx}^{2}} \over \verts{1 + yx}}
+ {y - x \over 1 + yx} = \mbox{constant}
$$

Answer (score 1):

Maple says:
$$
\arctan \left( x \right) -\int ^{-\arctan \left( x \right) +\arctan
 \left( y \left( x \right)  \right) }\!{\frac {2-\cos \left( 4\,t+4
 \right) -2\,\cos \left( 2\,t \right) +2\,\cos \left( 2\,t+4 \right) -
\cos \left( 4 \right) +\sqrt {4\,\cos \left( 4\,t+8 \right) -2\,\cos
 \left( 8+2\,t \right) -2\,\cos \left( 6\,t+8 \right) -8\,\cos \left( 
4 \right) +16\,\cos \left( 2\,t+4 \right) -12\,\cos \left( 2\,t
 \right) -8\,\cos \left( 4\,t+4 \right) +12}}{2+\cos \left( 4\,t+4
 \right) +2\,\cos \left( 2\,t \right) +2\,\cos \left( 2\,t+4 \right) +
\cos \left( 4 \right) }}{dt}-C=0
$$

Comment: Hello,This is  math exam questions

Comment: Then either you copied down the question wrong or the exam had a typo.  There is certainly no solution that a student could be expected to find in an exam.

Answer (score 0):

Another CAS gave this "nice" expression 
$$x(y)=\frac{-2 c_1 y+2 c_1 \tan ^{-1}(y)-c_1^2-\tan ^{-1}(y)^2+2 y \tan ^{-1}(y)+1}{c_1^2
   y-2 c_1 y \tan ^{-1}(y)-2 c_1-y+y \tan ^{-1}(y)^2+2 \tan ^{-1}(y)}$$ which simplifies if $y(0)=0$ but does not change to be more pleasant.